# vba: create pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have to create a pivot table using vba but i got the following error: "Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method" about this code: `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R1048576C8", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        pivotTableWs!R1C1, tableName:=tableName, DefaultVersion:=6`

here the complete source

```
Dim tableName As String
Dim pivotTableWs As Worksheet

tableName = "pivotTableName"

Set pivotTableWs = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("Sheet1"))
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet1!R1C1:R1048576C8", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    pivotTableWs!R1C1, tableName:=tableName, DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets(pivotTableWs).Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tableName)
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .SaveData = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = False
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .InGridDropZones = False
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = False
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tableName).PivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tableName).RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tableName).PivotFields("field1")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tableName).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    tableName).PivotFields("ticketid"), "Count of field1", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tableName).PivotFields("field2")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

I create this code using "Developer" tab, selected "Macro register" and i create pivot table manually

Comment: Change the TableDestination argument to `pivotTableWs.Cells(1, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added 2 Object variables `PvtTbl As PivotTable` and `PvtCache As PivotCache` to make the code more dynamic.

Other explanations are inside the code below (as comments).

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoPivot()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache

Dim PvtTblName As String
Dim pivotTableWs As Worksheet

PvtTblName = "pivotTableName"

' set the worksheet object where we will create the Pivot-Table
Set pivotTableWs = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets("Sheet1"))

' set the Pivot Cache (the Range is static)
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Sheet1!R1C1:R1048576C8")

' create a new Pivot Table in the new created sheet
Set PvtTbl = pivotTableWs.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=pivotTableWs.Range("A1"), TableName:=PvtTblName)

' after we set the PvtTbl object, we can easily modifty all it's properties
With PvtTbl
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .SaveData = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = False
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .InGridDropZones = False
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = False
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow

    With .PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With

    .RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels

    With .PivotFields("field1")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    .AddDataField .PivotFields("ticketid"), "Count of field1", xlCount

    With .PivotFields("field2")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need for a loop. This is what I used (with comments). It should work with any dataset.

```
Sub createPivot()
'declare Range variable
Dim dataRange As Range  


'get last row and last column in the data sheet
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'set value for  dataRange; this is dynamic and will work for any dataset
Set dataRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
dataRange.Select

'create new WS and insert blank pivot table
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot"
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, dataRange, 6).CreatePivotTable Sheets("Pivot").Range("A3"), "PivotTable1", dataRange, 6


' the following 2 blocks are optional
'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Rights Holder")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Values fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Number of tracks")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlSum
End With

End Sub
```