# Add pivot table using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

The problem I am facing with adding pivot table to a table is that my source data in the following code. If my reference code keeps changing, how do i format my source data?

SourceData: "Test!R35C1:R86C13" keepps changing 
Sometime my table lies on row 35, sometimes on row 40 or row 100. How do I make this dynamic?

Comment: If I'm reading your request right, it sounds like this walk through should help https://www.contextures.com/xlPivot01.html Used it to create a pivot table that "grows" with the source data as more data is added to the table. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the help. What I am seeking of how I could do that in excel VBA - To dynamically change my source data

Comment: There are existing posts addressing what you've asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541291/vba-create-pivot-table and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487657/how-to-create-pivot-table-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Function table_range()

'return the range of the source table

first_cell = Find_First_Used_Cell()
last_cell = Range_Find_Method(Range(first_cell))

table_range = first_cell + ":" + last_cell

End Function


Function Find_First_Used_Cell()
'modified
'original source: https://www.excelcampus.com/library/find-the-first-used-cell-vba-macro/

'Finds the first non-blank cell in a worksheet.

Dim rFound As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rFound = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If rFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "All cells are blank."
    Else
        'MsgBox "First Cell: " & rFound.Address
        Find_First_Used_Cell = rFound.Address
    End If


End Function


Function Range_Find_Method(rng As Range)
'modified
'original source: https://www.excelcampus.com/library/find-the-first-used-cell-vba-macro/

'Finds the first non-blank cell in a worksheet.

Dim rFound As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rFound = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=rng, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If rFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "All cells are blank."
    Else
        'MsgBox "First Cell: " & rFound.Address
        Range_Find_Method = rFound.Address
    End If
End Function
```

Now you can simply get the range like this:

```
Sub print_my_range()

Set my_range = Range(table_range())

MsgBox (my_range.Address)

End Sub
```